# Filtrar datos de un gridview segun una segunda tabla

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Estimados,

Tengo la siguiente duda, en visual basic, con base de datos sql server, quiero que en un datagridview se me muestre los datos de una tabla de mi base de datos llamada listado_marcas_autos, pero que se filtre sin mostrar las marcas de los autos que estan almacenadas en otra tabla que se llama marcas_ya_ingresadas

por ejemplo, la tabla listado_marcas_autos contiene las marcas de todos los autos que serian: chevrolet, toyota, kia, jeep, hyndai
si yo en la otra tabla llamada marcas_ya_ingresadas que en un comienzo esta vacia, ingreso la marca "toyota". entonces al cargar el gridview deberia mostrar todas las marcas que salen en la tabla listado_marcas_autos, exceptuando las marcas que esten en la tabla marcas_ya_ingresadas, en este caso "toyota".

Comment: Puedes poner lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pienso que la consulta sería así:

```
SELECT LMA.*  
FROM listado_marcas_autos AS LMA  
FULL JOIN marcas_ya_ingresadas AS MYI ON LMA.ID = MYI.ID  
WHERE MYI.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué crees que tu respuesta es la solución al problema

Comment: AlanV, revisa por favor [answer]!, y realiza el [tour] del sitio.

Comment: Me sirvio Alan! Muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda! @AlanV